# Neo4j 3 not starting on Ubuntu 12.04 boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, neo4j, boot

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 VM running Neo4j 3.0.5 Community Edition.  I can get it to start fine using `sudo /usr/bin/neo4j console`.

Ok.  That's great.  Good that.

Now, I want Neo4j to start when the system boots.  SO, I edit my /etc/rc.local file as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Start neo4j
/usr/bin/neo4j console &
echo test > /home/neoadmin/testfile

exit 0
```

When I restart, I do indeed see `test` sitting in testfile.  But no neo4j.

I have seen different approaches to this using Neo4j 2 (which are no longer relevant), or using it as a service with the deprecated `neo4j start` rather than the recommended `neo4j console`.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering: as setting up a new VM should be a matter of minutes; why on earth are you restricting yourself to a 4 year old version of ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried the neo4j debian packages from http://debian.neo4j.org/? Not sure if that works with an outdated Ubuntu release, but worth a try.